# Changing "Chapter 3" to "My chapter III" and no change in the remaining chapters

Tags: chapters

I have the simple following document:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Title of Chapter First}
This is my chapter first.
\chapter{Title of Chapter Two}  
This is my chapter two.
\chapter{Title of Chapter Three}    
This is my chapter three.
\end{document}
```

In normal mode, the Chapter 3 will be printed as follows:

```
Chapter 3
Title of chapter three
```

Now, I would like to see Chapter 3 in the following format

```
My Chapter III
Title of chapter three
```

instead of

```
Chapter 3
Title of chapter three
```

and format of the remaining chapters stays unchanged. In other words, only for Chapter 3, the words "Chapter" and "3" turned to "My Chapter" and roman numeral "III", respectively. Is there a proper way to do these things?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can redefine `\chaptername` to `My Chapter` and the style of the counter `chapter` to `\Roman`. The braces take care that the changes are only local to this chapter heading. In case you use them: a running header and the table of contents will reflect these changes, which may or may not be what you want.

```
{\renewcommand\chaptername{My Chapter}%
 \renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}%
 \chapter{Title of Chapter Three}%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as gernot, but in case someone wants to use babel, for example for French, you may use :

```
\addto\captionsfrench{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{My Chapter}}
```

instead. Replace *french* with your language.